# react pages css is getting mixed up even though in seperate folder for both pages

Tags: css, reactjs

I have 2 different pages sign-in and signup both are in separate folders with their own index.css(1 index.css for 1 page) but they are somehow using each other's CSS. if I make changes in one CSS file it also reflects on another page. I have imported them into their respective pages. I am kinda new to development.. please help.

Answer (score 0):

you should add a specific classname for each tag in your project same classes take same styles

Answer (score 0):

add class names in different files, not make them unique the best practice right now is to use CSS Modules. Check here for more info :

[CSS Modules React document](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/)

with them, you can have the same name in different files, which react make them unique automatically